# How to properly override a default spartacus Component

Tags: spartacus-storefront

For the most part overriding an existing Spartacus works fine.

The Minimum amount of effort is

```
B2cStorefrontModule.withConfig({
      cmsComponents: {
        DefaultComponent: {
          component: CustomComponent
        }
      },
```

Mostly I do this because I need to apply some changes to the components html.
So I copy and paste it to my generated customComponent.
But most of the times this html contains directives and pipes that require adding additional Modules to my app.modules. 
Sometimes this works fine, but in many other cases the html just wont render.

Example: SearchBoxComponent

when trying to use the html I get a browser Error:

```
Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'cxHighlight' could not be found ("
      <a
        *ngFor="let suggestion of result.suggestions"
        [innerHTML]="[ERROR ->]suggestion | cxHighlight: searchInput.value"
        [routerLink]="
          {
"): ng:///AppModule/EmvSearchBoxComponent.html@49:21
```

In other cases I was able to fix this by including the corresponding module that references this pipe "cxHighlight". In this case "SearchBoxModule". But still no good.

How do make this pipe available in my project?
Or maybe there is an even better way around all this importing pain?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in the way you are overriding components in Spartacus. Like you noticed certain components contain pipes so you will have to manually import those in your components module. This is just the Angular way.

Most of our pipes are reused in multiple components so we try to make them have their own modules to make imports easier.

You are correct about `cxHighlight`, there is a bug. The pipe is declared in the `SearchBoxModule` but not exported so it's pretty much impossible to import. I will open an [issue](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/7556) to have it fixed.